# PHP Instantiating a Class that Extends an Abstract Class

Tags: php, class, instantiation, abstract

So I am using an abstract class for the first time in PHP and am struggling to get it working. It is probably simple (as ever!). When I try to instantiate the class B, PHP throws this error 
 Fatal error: **Class 'B' not found in /var/www/test/class/B.class.php on line 12**

***Abstract Class A***

```
abstract class A
{
    public function A()
    {
        //do something...
    } 
}
```

**Class B**

```
include 'A.class.php';  //abstract class A is in a different file

$b = new B();    //instantiate class B (Line 12, error points to here)

class B extends A
{

    public function B() 
    {
        //do something...
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not a PHP export, but have you tried putting your new B(); AFTER the declaration of class B instead of before it?

Comment: Correct. OP is thinking like Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move $b = new B(); below the class definition.

Comment: Thank you man, as ever it was right in front of me! I believe the reason I made the mistake is because I am so used to instantiating classes from other files just before a new class, old projects coming back to haunt me! Thanks again.